# Multiple Celery instances consuming a single queue

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

Is it possible to have multiple celery instances possible on different machines consuming from a single queue for tasks, working with django preferably using django-orm as the backend?
How can i implement this if possible, I can't seem to find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, they just have to use the same [broker](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/). For instance, if you are using AMQP, the configs on your servers must share the same

`BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:password@localhost:5672//'`

See the [routing page](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) for more details. For instance let's say you want to have a common queue for two servers, then one specific to each of them, you could do

### On server 1:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {'your_app.your_specific_tasks1': {'queue': 'server1'}}
user@server1:/$ celery -A your_celery_app worker -Q server1, default
```

### On server 2:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {'your_app.your_specific_tasks2': {'queue': 'server2'}}
user@server2:/$ celery -A your_celery_app worker -Q server2, default
```

Of course it's optional, by default all the tasks will be routed to the queue named `celery`.

Comment: Is it necessary to add CELERY_ROUTES in this case? Can i use the automatic routing, what is happening right now is i am trying it with two celery workers on 2 machines and both the workers start the task.

Comment: Not it's not. The only thing that matters here is that the workers share the same broker, so they will consume from the same (default) queue named `celery`.